# Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.how to resolve it?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I want to show my data from SQLite DB to RecyclerView in fragment inside an activity. iget error in line:contactList.add(m); in Databese helper getAllUsers method.

this is my logcat:

```
09-17 18:11:17.487 2101-2101/ir.shirazmetro E/CursorWindow: Failed to read row 0, column 1 from a CursorWindow which has 17 rows, 1 columns.
09-17 18:11:17.487 2101-2101/ir.shirazmetro D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


    --------- beginning of crash
09-17 18:11:17.487 2101-2101/ir.shirazmetro E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ir.shirazmetro, PID: 2101
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
        at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
        at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:438)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
        at ir.shirazmetro.DatabaseHelper.getAllUsers(DatabaseHelper.java:89)
        at ir.shirazmetro.views.fragments.toDastgheybFragment.onActivityCreated(toDastgheybFragment.java:58)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2344)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1446)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1754)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1822)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2591)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2378)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2333)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2210)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:649)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:145)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1239)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1087)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1617)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:875)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:141)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1173)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1379)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Cho
```

here is my code:

Activity.java:

```
public class station extends BaseActivity {
    Toolbar mToolbar;
    private TabLayout tbLayout;
    private ViewPager vPager;
    private ButtonCell backBtn;
    Boolean btnOneOn = false;
    Boolean btnTwoOn = false;
    Boolean btnThreeOn = false;
    Boolean btnfourOn = false;
    ButtonCell Button2;
    ButtonCell Button1;
    ButtonCell Button3;
    ButtonCell Button4;

    private List<DatabaseModel> LineList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private DataAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_station);

        mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.tlbr1);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        DatabaseHelper helpher;
        helpher = new DatabaseHelper(station.this);
        helpher.insertIntoDB("dastgheyb", "06:10:00", "B");
        helpher.close();
        initView();
        setupWithViewPager();
        tbLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

and this is DataAdapter.java:

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private List<DatabaseModel> LineList;
    public Context mContext;

    public DataAdapter(Context mContext, List<DatabaseModel> line1List) {
        this.LineList = line1List;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextViewCell Time;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            //initialize textViews and buttons
            Time = view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //set item layout using layout inflater
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_to_dastgheyb, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final DatabaseModel list = LineList.get(position);
        holder.Time.setText(list.getTime());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return LineList.size();
    }
}
```

And this is my fragment.java:

```
public class toDastgheybFragment extends BaseFragment {
    private Activity mActivity = null;
    private View mView;
    private RecyclerFragmentListener mFragmentListener = null;

    // RecyclerViewとAdapter
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    DataAdapter mAdapter;

    public interface RecyclerFragmentListener {
        void onRecyclerEvent();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_to_dastgheyb, container, false);
        mRecyclerView = mView.findViewById(R.id.myRecycler);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mActivity));
        return mView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        Cursor cursor;
        List<DatabaseModel> LineList = new ArrayList<>();
        LineList.clear();
        DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());
        //data from database is returned to m
        final List<DatabaseModel> m = db.getAllUsers();
        Log.w("SIZe", "" + m.size());
        //if m contains data
        if (m.size() > 0) {
            //loop through contents
            for (int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++) {
                Log.w("NAME", m.get(i).getTime());
                //add data to list used in adapter
                LineList.add(m.get(i));
                //notify data change
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        db.close();

        mAdapter = new DataAdapter(mActivity, LineList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    public void onRecyclerClicked(View v, int position) {

    }
}
```

and this is my DataHelper.java:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MetroDB";//name of the database
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "stationtime";//name for the table

    private static final String Station = "station";
    private static final String Time = "time";
    private static final String Line = "line";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        //Query to create table in databse
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + Station + " TEXT," + Time + " TEXT," + Line + " TEXT);";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }

    //Executes once a database change is occurred
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    //method to add row to table
    void addToLine1(DatabaseModel m) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(Station, m.getStation());

        values.put(Time, m.getTime());

        values.put(Line, m.getLine());


        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public void insertIntoDB(String station,String time,String line) {
        // 1. get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db1 = this.getWritableDatabase();

        // 2. create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("station", station);
        values.put("time", time);
        values.put("line", line);

        // 3. insert
        db1.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        // 4. close
        db1.close();
    }

    //method to list all details from table
    public List<DatabaseModel> getAllUsers() {
        List<DatabaseModel> contactList = new ArrayList<DatabaseModel>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT " + Time + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + ";";//retrieve data from the database
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if (cursor.getCount()>0) {
            do {
                DatabaseModel m = new DatabaseModel();
                //                m.setStation(cursor.getString(0));
                m.setTime(cursor.getString(1));
                //              m.setLine(cursor.getString(2));
                contactList.add(m);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return contactList;
    }
}
```

and also DatabaseModel.java:

```
public class DatabaseModel {
    String station, time, line;

    public DatabaseModel() {
    }

    public DatabaseModel(String station, String time, String line) {
        this.station = station;
        this.time = time;
        this.line = line;
    }

    public String getStation() {
        return station;
    }

    public void setStation(String station) {
        this.station = station;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getLine() {
        return line;
    }

    public void setLine(String line) {
        this.line = line;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which is the Error you are getting? Also if you can add the stack trace to the question.

Comment: here you are. the logcat return is attached to my post

Answer (score 1):

> Failed to read row 0, column 1 from a CursorWindow which has 17 rows,
>   1 columns.

I think the problem you have is actually in line `DatabaseHelper.java` line `89`, which I guess would be `m.setTime(cursor.getString(1));`

Specifically the part failing should be `cursor.getString(1)`

The query you are running has only one column whose index should be 0 instead of 1.

There is an easier way not to get in this kind of troubble. You can access the columns by name.

```
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(String columnName));
```

As `Time` holds the name of the `time` field, in this case it would be:

```
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Time));
```

Here you pass in `Time` as the column name and it should return the correct column.

**ISSUE 2**

> the error change to :java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke
>   virtual method 'void
>   ir.shirazmetro.views.adapters.DataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()' on a
>   null object reference

Check in the `Fragment`, the initialization of `mAdapter` is at the bottom of the method, after you run the query and call `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`.

That is why you get the `NPE`. If you put a breakpoint on that line, you will see that `mAdapter` is null.

If possible initialize the adapter (`mAdapter = new DataAdapter(mActivity, LineList);`) in the `Fragment`'s `onCreate()` method.

Instead of passing `mActivity`, you can call the `Fragment`'s `getActivity();`

By the way I think `mActivity` is never set. `Fragments` can be tricky regarding the activity. I would remove that reference and always depend on calling `getActivity()` in the Fragment.

Comment: you mean i must write m.setTime(cursor.getString(getColumnIndex(String time)); ???

Comment: no it dosn't work .the error change to :java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void ir.shirazmetro.views.adapters.DataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()' on a null object reference

Comment: appreciate that.

Comment: i think i get the NPE error because of the LineList size every time is 0. and i don't know why.

Comment: Did you see the update in the answer where it says Issue 2. The error message is telling you where the error is raising. It is when you call notifyDataSetChange(). You are calling it on mAdapter. If you set a breakpoint you will see it is null because it hasn't been initialized yet. Because you initialize it after the call is made.

Answer (score -1):

when use `rawQuery`, **The SQL string must not be ; terminated**, but in your codes:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT " + Time + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + ";";
```

which should be:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT " + Time + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
```